# How to make a "real" immutable list of Date objects in guava

Tags: java, date, guava, immutability

How can I make an immutable list of date (java.util.Date) using guava?

I have this snippet:

```
    Date date = new GregorianCalendar(2014, 4, 1).getTime();    

    // doesn't work: 
    // List<Date> immutableList = ImmutableList.of(date);
    // doesn't work either:
    List<Date> immutableList = ImmutableList.copyOf(new Date[] { date });

    date.setMonth(3);

    System.out.println("immutableList has: " + immutableList.get(0));
```

Whereas I want to make it a "real" immutable list, so that 0th element will not be changed, when the `date` object is changed.

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 7):

As you have already found out, using an immutable list protects the list from modification, but does nothing to safeguard the elements contained in the list. For that, the elements themselves have to be immutable.

Unfortunately, it's not possible to create immutable `java.util.Date` objects. There's a couple of approaches you could consider:

1. If you're using Java 8, use the immutable date/time value classes introduced by [JSR-310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310). You can find an introductory article [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-date-time-2125367.html).
2. If you're not using Java 8, your best bet would be to use the immutable classes from the [Joda Time library](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/).
3. Write your own date wrapper class that protects the wrapped date object from modification.
4. While objects of type `java.util.Date` are mutable, objects of type `java.lang.Long` are immutable.
   You could therefore create an immutable list of `Long` objects to store the `long` values obtained from calling [`Date.getTime()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime()), and construct new date objects on the fly using the [`Date(long date)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date(long)) constructor when retrieving from the list.

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

- No need for [Guava](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Guava). Built-in features suffice.
- `List.of` & `List.copyOf` in Java 9 & 10 respectively produce unmodifiable `List` implementations.
- Use modern *java.time* classes, never `Date` nor `Calendar`.

  - The *java.time* objects are immutable, their state cannot be altered.

Example:

```
List.copyOf(                                          // Produce an unmodifiable `List` based on elements drawn from another `Collection` in iteration-order. 
    LocalDate.of( 2014 , Month.MARCH , 1 )            // Modern class to represent a date-only value, without time-of-day and without time zone.
    .datesUntil(                                      // Generates a stream of `LocalDate` objects, incrementing one day at a time. 
        LocalDate.of( 2014 , Month.APRIL , 1 )        // The `LocalDate` class is designed to produce immutable objects, with state that can be read but not altered (not “mutated”). 
    )                                                 // Returns a `Stream<LocalDate>`.
    .collect(                                         // Processes the series of dates coming from the stream.
        Collectors.toCollection( ArrayList :: new )   // Creates a `List`, and adds the series of dates to that list. 
    )                                                 // Returns a `List<LocalDate>`. 
)                                                     // Returns another `List<LocalDate>` whose elements cannot be added, dropped, or replaced from the collection.
.toString()                                           // Generates a `String` with text representing the value of each contained `LocalDate` object.
```

> [2014-03-01, 2014-03-02, 2014-03-03, 2014-03-04, 2014-03-05, 2014-03-06, 2014-03-07, 2014-03-08, 2014-03-09, 2014-03-10, 2014-03-11, 2014-03-12, 2014-03-13, 2014-03-14, 2014-03-15, 2014-03-16, 2014-03-17, 2014-03-18, 2014-03-19, 2014-03-20, 2014-03-21, 2014-03-22, 2014-03-23, 2014-03-24, 2014-03-25, 2014-03-26, 2014-03-27, 2014-03-28, 2014-03-29, 2014-03-30, 2014-03-31]

## No need for Guava

The [Google Guava](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Guava) library is extremely useful in many ways. However, it is no longer needed to accomplish your goal of a read-only data structure for a series of dates. Java now has built-in features to support this.

## java.time

The modern approach uses the *java.time* classes that supplanted the terrible old date-time classes such as `Date` & `Calendar`.

### `LocalDate`

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

Your Question is not clear. Seems like maybe what you wanted was a list of dates from the previous month.

```
LocalDate stop = LocalDate.of( 2014 , Month.APRIL , 1 ) ;  // Sane numbering: `2014` is the year 2014, and 1-12 = Jan-Dec.
LocalDate start = stop.minusMonths( 1 ) ;
```

You can use the Java Streams facility to generate the series of `LocalDate` objects. First make a `Stream< LocalDate >`.

```
Stream< LocalDate > streamOfLocalDates = start.datesUntil( stop ) ;
```

Then, collect the series of `LocalDate` objects emitted from that stream into a `List` collection.

```
List< LocalDate > localDates = 
    streamOfLocalDates.collect( 
        Collectors.toCollection( ArrayList::new ) 
    )
;
```

The `List` produced above is modifiable, meaning we can add, drop, or replace its elements. To protect against such changes to the `List`,  produce another `List`, an unmodifiable `List`, using the new `List.copyOf` feature in Java 10 and later.

```
List< LocalDate > localDatesUnmodifiable = 
    List.copyOf( 
        localDates 
    ) 
;
```

We have two levels of protection in place here to protect against changes to our data.

- Using [`List.copyOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/List.html#copyOf(java.util.Collection)) protects you from adding, dropping, or replacing elements within the list. It does nothing to stop you from modifying the state *within* the object stored in each element.
- The fact that the *java.time* classes use the [immutable objects pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object) protects you from changes in your elements’ object’s state.

So a `List.copyOf( List< LocalDate > )` cannot be modified in its elements nor in their content, a completely read-only data structure.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

No way. If you really want to use `Date`, you have to clone each `get()` result in order to protect the stored value. You also have to clone the dates you put in, unless you're sure they won't change afterwards.

The best thing you can do is to switch to some immutable datatype. Otherwise, you have to wrap all accesses, which is a real pain. You could base your `List` on `long[]` instead (this is probably less error-prone than adapting a list, as there's no chance of mistakenly publishing a stored object).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a choice, but to use Date object, then you can always return a copy of the dates object. This will make your object Immutable.

```
public final class ImmutableDates{
    private final List<Date> dates;
    // other final fields 

    // constructor with final dates and other final fields as argument

    // don't expose setter

    // always create and return a new list populated with new dates
    public List<Date> getDates() {
        List<Date> newDates = dates.stream().map(p -> new Date(p.getTime())).collect(Collectors.toList());
        return newDates;
    }
}
```

**Always create and return a new list populated with new dates**